# Tensorboard: ImportError: cannot import name 'main'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorboard

I made a summary file from a python 3.6.3 script with tensorflow 1.10.0 into a directory called 'summaries'.

Then, when I typed `tensorboard --logdir==summaries/`,
I got the following error:

```
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\Scripts\tensorboard.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'main'
```

Can someone point me to how this can be fixed?

Comment: Are you sure that's the whole traceback?  The actual line of code that is causing the error seems to be missing -- it should be between the `<module>` line and the `ImportError` line.

Comment: If you're building TensorFlow from source, try `pip install tb-nightly`

Comment: I did try pip `install tb-nightly` but I'm still getting the same error. And that was my whole traceback.

Answer (score 2):

try
    pip install --upgrade tensorflow-tensorboard